# how to create a dropdown menu without damaging a snippet

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

https://github.com/nedzone/uht-yniversitet hi so here you can check my code and I'm asking can you help me make an dropdown menu with

```
<div class="boxwhitetop"> <!-- бяла част на менюто -->
    <ul class="snip1488"> <!-- меню горна лента -->
      <li class="current"><a href="#">Начало</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Факултети</a>
        <ul>
          <a href="#">1</a>
          <a href="#">2</a>
          <a href="#">3</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ръководство</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Спортен комплекс</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Новини</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Разсписи</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: 'How to' is not a proper question on SO... please show us what you have tried and what went wrong.

Comment: i tried to use css dropdown it didnt work it looks ugly couse of the snippet i want not to brake the snippet just to add dropdown menu to an single UL button

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that ... and This is a simple One according to Your code :

#### HTML

```
<div class="boxwhitetop"> <!-- бяла част на менюто -->

<!-- button to open/close the menu  --> 
<button class ="menu" >Menu</button>

<ul class="snip1488"> <!-- меню горна лента -->
  <li class="current"><a href="#">Начало</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Факултети</a>
      <ul>
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Ръководство</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Спортен комплекс</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Новини</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Разсписи</a></li>
  </ul>
```

#### JS Script

```
$(".menu").Click(function(){

      $(this).siblings(".snip1488").slideToggle(300);

 });
```

I hope It was useful

Comment: it isnt  useful.. it didnt help me . Doesnt change anything on the code on me .. can you be more accurate please :)

Comment: @NedkoBoqnov  this's the full code check it , It must work https://github.com/BlacKnight-RH/stackOverFlow/commit/364096e68764b1c3752cd80086912a8ae6b432c8

Answer (score 0):

If you want a horizontal menu with dropdown, you can do this using just CSS. You should make the list items `display: inline-block` and then toggle the submenu's with `display: block/none` on hover. Like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXPPyB